# Generate values from a frequency distribution

Tags: python, matlab, frequency-distribution

I'm currently analyzing a 16 bit binary string - something like 0010001010110100. I have approximately 30 of these strings. I have written a simple program in Matlab that counts the numbers of 1's in each bit for all 30 strings.

So, for example:

1 30

2 15

3 1

4 10

etc

I want to generate more strings (100s) that roughly follow the frequency distribution above. Is there a Matlab (or Python or R) command that does that?

What I'm looking for is something like this: http://www.prenhall.com/weiss_dswin/html/simulate.htm

Comment: If you only have 30 strings how does 2 (I assume that's a bit position) get a count of 45?

Comment: That was just an example.

Comment: I don't get the logic that you are trying to explain. Why not just show your real data, and the output that you expect?

Comment: Thanks for fixing that confusing sample data. In Python 3.6+ you can use [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB: just use `<` (or `lt`, less than) on `rand`:

```matlab
len = 16; % string length
% counts of 1s for each bit (just random integer here)
counts = randi([0 30],[1 len]); 
% probability for 1 in each bit
prob = counts./30;
% generate 100 random strings 
n = 100;
moreStrings = rand(100,len);
% for each bit check if number is less than the probability of the bit
moreStrings = bsxfun(@lt, moreStrings, prob); % lt(x,y) := x < y
```

In Python:

```python
import numpy as np

len = 16 # string length
# counts of 1's for each bit (just random integer here)
counts = np.random.randint(0, 30, (1,16)).astype(float)
# probability for 1 in each bit
prob = counts/30
# generate 100 random strings 
n = 100
moreStrings = np.random.rand(100,len)
# for each bit check if number is less than the probability of the bit
moreStrings = moreStrings < prob
```